# Postfix SMTP sends to localhost, ignores MX records set to Google Apps

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, g-suite

I have the MX records for `zaltin.com` set to the Google Apps domains (`aspmx.l.google.com` etc.). If an email is sent to `kerrick@zaltin.com` from most places, it goes to my Google Apps account. However, on the `zaltin.com` server (Ubuntu 10.04 if it matters), sending via SMTP (postfix), if I send to `kerrick@zaltin.com` (via the `Pony` ruby gem if it matters), it simply routes to `kerrick@localhost` (showing up via the `mail` command) instead of going to my Google Apps account (where it should show up in my GApps Gmail inbox).

Can I make email sent via SMTP *on* my server, *through* my server, not go *to* my server but to Google Apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either have an entry in `/etc/hosts` pointing `zaltin.com` to localhost, like this:

```
127.0.0.1   zaltin.com
```

In which case you need to remove this, or you've configured Postfix to treate `zaltin.com` as a local destination in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` like this:

```
mydestination = localhost, zaltin.com
```

In which case you need to remove this.

Comment: Ah, I believe it's the second one. If I remove that, can I still send email _from_ zaltin.com via postfix?

Comment: @Kerrick Yup, that doesn't restrict what From addresses you can use. As an aside, you should however setup SPF records.

Comment: Yay, editing it out of that line fixed it! And I'll look into SPF records, thank you.